# 'File' object does not have a 'path' property. (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I am passing a `File` object that comes from the browser (by dropping) to a function like this:

```
// .... logic here...
accept(file)

public static accept(file: File) {
   console.log(file)
   /* prints:
      => lastModified: 1555453309243
         lastModifiedDate: Wed Apr 17 2019 01:21:49 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00) {}
         name: "test.txt"
         path: "test.txt" --> as you can see there is a path variable in here.
         size: 16
         type: "text/plain"
         webkitRelativePath: ""
         __proto__: File
   */

   console.log(file.name) // => prints 'test.txt'
   console.log(file.size) // => prints '16'
   console.log(file.path) // => !! error given. path does not exists in File object. Also IDE does not show this parameter in IDE autocomplete list.
}
```

Error given:

```
Property 'path' does not exist on type 'File'.ts(2339)
```

Why `File` does not have `path` parameter? How can I make sure path exists? Is there any other type for `File`? This is a HTML5 drop.

If I do this:

```
public static accept(file: any) {
   alert(file.path);
}
```

It shows the relative path:

[image: path]

Comment: I can access it. This is HTML5 Drag&Drop project. I've updated the question. Have a look into this. I just can't use with static typing. How can I trick the IDE and webpack that it has a `path` in it.?

Comment: If the property _is_ there, you can always access it by `(file as any).path`.

Comment: @mbojko Yup, that did the trick. Thanks! You can write this as an answer.

Comment: Ideally you'd make your own interface like `interface MyFile extends File { path: string; /* etc */ }` and use that.  Where is it documented that `File` has a `path` property, though?  You should be aware if you are only supporting some particular or nonstandard environment.

Comment: So, this is bothering me.  What browser are you using that `File` has a `path` property?  I've tried [these](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API#Examples_and_demos) using Firefox and Chrome and none of them have a `path`.

Comment: @jcalz Chrome latest version. Using React-Dropzone. It has path property and it has relative path info when drag and drop a folder into a browser.

Comment: @jcalz: try this: https://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/dnd/all_types_of_import.html. Even dropbox has a folder upload capability on supported browsers. BTW, I will go with your way. Its more concise. (I believe, ReactDropzone smart enough to capture path on each browser and put it on path property)

Comment: Ah, so React-Dropzone is adding this property.  I'd think this should be part of the TypeScript typings for React-Dropzone then... perhaps a `DropZoneFile` or `DropZoneFolder` which extends `File` with an optional `path` property?  Since they haven't done it in the library then I guess you need to do it for your own code.

Comment: It's in the source code [here](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone/blob/6f0e826f6337367ab8b47efaa04449d839594c2a/typings/react-dropzone.d.ts#L3). Use it as `import { useDropzone, FileWithPath } from 'react-dropzone';`

Answer (score 22):

For anyone else using `react-dropzone`, it seems they're getting the typing for `FileWithPath` from this library `file-selector`

See line 3 here:
https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone/blob/master/typings/react-dropzone.d.ts

You can simply import this `FileWithPath` from `react-dropzone` wherever you need it.

Answer (score 17):

Kitson's answer is correct. I just wanted to add the exact way to implement this answer for those newer to Typescript. If you are just starting with the Basic Example in Dropzone's docs, you can just add `FileWithPath` to your imports from `react-dropzone` and define the type of each file coming from the map. Note the two additions of `FileWithPath` here:

```
import { useDropzone, FileWithPath } from "react-dropzone";
 
function Basic(props) {
  const {acceptedFiles, getRootProps, getInputProps} = useDropzone();
 
  const files = acceptedFiles.map((file: FileWithPath) => (
    <li key={file.path}>
      {file.path} - {file.size} bytes
    </li>
  ));
...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
interface FileWithPath extends File {
  path: string
}

const path = (file as FileWithPath).path
```